# I need to output this mysql_fetch_assoc array to a table with maximum of 5 columns per row.

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, html-table

I have this table:

```
img id  | img_path   | listing_assoc_id|
----------------------------------------
   11   |img/img1.jpg |       12        |
   12   |img/img2.jpg |       12        |
   13   |img/img3.jpg |       12        |
   14   |img/img4.jpg |       12        | 
   15   |img/img5.jpg |       12        |
   16   |img/img6.jpg |       12        |
   18   |img/img7.jpg |       12        |
   21   |img/img8.jpg |       12        |
   22   |img/img9.jpg |       12        |
   23   |img/img10.jpg|       12        |
   24   |img/img11.jpg|       12        |
```

And I want to display it into a table in html
like this maximum of 5 images per row. I have been fiddling with different loops in combination of different loops like above for a couple hours but haven't found one that works like I need. They are either displaying the same images across the entire row or are messed up in some other way. Obviously need to use tr & td elements to format table correctly. 
What I need:

```
     <tr>
     <td>img1</td> <td>img2</td> <td>img3</td> <td>img4</td> <td>img5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>img6</td> <td>img7</td> <td>img8</td> <td>img9</td> <td>img10</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>img11</td> 
     </tr>
```

Some of the code that doesn't work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM listings_gallery WHERE listing_assoc_id = " 12 " ORDER BY img_id ASC";
    $image_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    echo '<tr>';
        while($img = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set)){
            while($img['img_id'] < 5){
            echo "<td><img src='" . $img['img_path'] . "'></td>";
            }
            echo '<tr>'; 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't actually depend on the image ID.  You could use `% 5` to do this, but the IDs may be out of order, etc.  Instead, you can just fetch everything into an array and use `array_chunk`

```
$img = array();
while ($img = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set)) {
    $imgs[] = $img;
}
foreach (array_chunk($imgs, 5) as $img_chunk) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($img_chunk as $img) {
        echo "<td>$img</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

This is probably about as simple as it gets but it's not as memory efficient as could be.  You could also maintain your own counter and check `% 5` for that to break out of the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks! This works to display properly however I need to conserve the **actual** img_id. I realize I didn't specify that previously however what I did to tackle the problem was to use divs inline-block instead & I could conserve the img_id without much effort. I don't know why I didn't use divs before.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images_rows = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$images = array();
while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($images_rows)) {
   $images[] = $image;
}
echo '<table><tr>';
$ct = 0;
$ctt = 0;
$size = sizeOf($images) - 1;
foreach($images as $image){
     if($ct == 5) {
       echo '<tr>';
       $ct = 0;
     }
     echo "<td><img src='" . $image['img_path'] . "'></td>"; 
     $ct++; 
     $ctt++;
     echo ($ct == 5 && $ctt != $size) ? '</tr>': '';
}
echo '</tr></table>'
```